# fadeIn and fadeOut text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I show and hide text in timely fashion ?

this is what I've got:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#show_and_hide1').delay(5000).fadeOut();
        $('#show_and_hide2').delay(1000).fadeIn();
        $('#show_and_hide2').show();
        $('#show_and_hide2').delay(5000).fadeOut();
        $('#show_and_hide3').delay(1000).fadeIn();
        $('#show_and_hide3').show();
        $('#show_and_hide3').delay(5000).fadeOut();
        $('#show_and_hide4').delay(1000).fadeIn();
        $('#show_and_hide4').show();
        $('#show_and_hide4').delay(5000).fadeOut();

      });
    </script>
```

html:

```
<div class="container" id="show_and_hide1">
  <p>...</p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="show_and_hide2">
   <p>...</p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="show_and_hide3">
  <p>...</p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="show_and_hide4">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Problem is this code shows first 2 texts (`#show_or_hide1` and `#show_or_hide2`) but then it won't show the rest in queue.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Not just the .show() but any call with `$().action` will occur immediately - so if you do `$("#id").delay(1000).fadeIn(); $("#id").delay(1000).slideDown()` it doesn't fadeIn, wait 1 second then slideDown - fadeIn and slideDown run at the same time (both after 1s delay)

Comment: Ideally, I want each text to be shown for about 5 secs.

Comment: freedomn-m The reason he's getting 'show us the HTML' is because showing a minimum working example is the standard. It's *very* hard to diagnose something speculatively.

Comment: You need to chain the animations (in simple terms, put them all on the same line), then they are queued - alternatively use jquery queue.  Example: `$("div").delay(1000).fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut()`

Comment: Previous comment (now deleted) is valid in that `.show()` will override any animations as it's instant.

Comment: Both [`fadeIn`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) support a callback function that runs when the animation has completed.

Comment: @Phil   Your input helped me. I just linked them all as callbacks. Feel free to post it as a suggested answer and I'll accept it.